# Frame Busting in the ad industry

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, framebusting

I'm trying to find a way to stop malicious ad IFrames from stealing top.location as they sometimes do (cheap traffic).

I used [Atwood's HTTP 204 solution](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/06/we-done-been-framed.html) but in my tests seems like it breaks some basic functionality like manually changing the url via address bar and the refresh button busted as well.

I thought I might be able to stop the bubbling of onbeforeunload event and use the busting code inside "middle" IFrame but I couldn't make it, the onbeforeunload event in the "middle" IFrame fires and bust any redirection try.

I was wondering, is there any other way to keep the functionality as is and yet bust the redirection coming from a specific Iframe?

Comment: If you're writing _HTML5_, take a look at the [_sandbox attribute_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox)

Comment: @PaulS. I definitely would have used that but flash plugin is required (inside the iframe)